# Regex Matches - Wildcard then one decimal place

Tags: regex

Trying to achieve the following:

Make a Regex Matches for:

Example: `*.0`

So Wildcard then a decimal point then a zero.

Reason I want this is because I want to do an IF statement for:

```
IF *.0 then add another Zero.
```

If anyone can help that would be great, or point me in the right direction!
Thanks.

Comment: It should be `/^\*\.0$/`

Comment: Which language are you aiming at? A JavaScript regex will look along the lines of `/\.0$/` (you don't need the leading `.*` unless you need to match the entire input string, that is `/^.*\.0$/`.) Or is "*" an input character, too?

Comment: @anubhava Please, avoid using comments to post answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word boundary \b

Wildcard .*

Dot \.

Number \d

```
/\b.*\.\d\b/g
```

**Edit:**
Thanks Alexander Pavlov for the reminder to set the boundary

Comment: This will match ".0" anywhere in the string, not only at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex:

```
\*\.0
```

OR

```
/\*\.0/g
```